# LDIF Parser in Java (LDIF->JSON)

Tags: java, json, ldap, ldif

Do you know any java library (or sth other maybe script?) that allows you to 'convert' LDIF to JSON?

JSON data is easier for me to process, So an easy way to make such conversion would be really useful. Also I don't want to reinvent the wheel:)

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://www.ldaptive.org/docs/guide/formatting.html) seems to be what you are after.

You should be able to do something like:

```
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
JsonWriter jsonWriter = new JsonWriter(writer);
FileReader reader = new FileReader("entry.ldif");
LdifReader ldifReader = new LdifReader(reader);
SearchResponse result = ldifReader.read();
jsonWriter.write(result);
System.out.println(writer.toString());
```

[Here](https://gist.github.com/schakko/896652) is a PHP script I found on github as well that does from ldif to JSON or XML.
I don't know the quality of it.

Comment: Anything for .net please?

Comment: Searched on Internet. The details that was available in Java 5 years back still not available in .Net . Quite strange.